# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^a \int_0^x t^{a-1} f(t) dt$ exists if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^b \int_0^x t^{b-1} f(t) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity, contest-math

> Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function that is continuous on $(0,1].$ Let $a,b>0$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^a \int_0^x t^{a-1} f(t) dt$ exists if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^b \int_0^x t^{b-1} f(t) dt$ exists.

It seems useful to define $F(x) = \int_0^x t^{a-1} f(t) dt$. Then $t^{b-1} f(t) = t^{b-a} F'(t)$. The idea is now to integrate by parts. Clearly by symmetry it is enough to show that if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^a F(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^b \int_0^x t^{b-1} f(t) dt$ exists. We see that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^b \int_0^x t^{b-1} f(t) dt = \lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/x^b \int_0^x t^{b-a} F'(t) dt = \lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{-b} \left[(t^{b-a} F(t))_0^x - (b-a) \int_0^x t^{b-a-1} F(t) dt\right] = \left[\lim_{x\to0^+} 1/x^a F(x) - 1/x^b (b-a) \int_0^x t^{b-a-1} F(t) dt\right].$$ Of course, even though $f$ is continuous on $(0,1]$, it may not be bounded; take $f(x)=1/x$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x=0$. I'm not sure if one can place a bound on $F(x)$. From above, we just need to show that $- 1/x^b (b-a)\int_0^x t^{b-a-1} F(t) dt$ exists to conclude the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems valid, but $a$ in the last limit makes the proof complicated.

Therefore, I found it is more easier (and clearer) to show the '$b=1$' case:
$$
\exists \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1}{x^a} \int_0^{x} t^{a-1} f(t) dt  \Longleftrightarrow \exists \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} f(t) dt \,.
$$
for every $a > 0$.

($\Rightarrow$) Let us say the left limit is $L$. For $x>0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} f(t) dt &= \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} \frac{1}{t^{a-1}}\cdot t^{a-1}f(t) dt \\
& \stackrel{(\spadesuit)}{=} \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{1}{x^{a-1}} \int_{0}^x t^{a-1}f(t) dt - \lim_{u\to 0+} \Big[ \frac{1}{u^{a-1}} \int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big] 
-\int_{0}^x \frac{1-a}{u^a}\Big(\int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big) du  \right)\\
&=  \frac{1}{x^a} \int_{0}^x t^{a-1}f(t) dt - \frac{1}{x} \lim_{u\to 0+} \Big[ u \cdot \frac{1}{u^{a}} \int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big] - \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^x \frac{1-a}{u^a}\Big(\int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big)du \,.
\end{align}
$$

Note that the $\lim_{x\to 0+}$ of the first term is $\pmb{L}$, and the second term is $0\cdot L = 0$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} f(t) dt = L - (1-a)\underline{\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^x \frac{1}{u^a}\Big(\int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big)du}\,.
$$

For showing the convergence of underlined integral limit, by the existence of $L$, for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, we have $\delta>0$ such that:
$$
0<u\leq\delta \Rightarrow (L-\epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{u^a}\int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \leq (L+\epsilon)\,.
$$
Now, we know the function of $u$ at the middle of inequality is bounded in $u\in(0,\delta]$. Thus, if $\pmb{0<x<\delta}$, by applying $\int_{0}^x du$ and $\cdot \frac{1}{x}$ simultaneously, we get:
$$
0<x<\delta \Rightarrow (L-\epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^x \frac{1}{u^a}\Big(\int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big)du \leq (L+\epsilon)\,.
$$

This exactly means that underlined limit exists and the value is $L$. Finally, we get:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} f(t) dt = L - (1-a)L = \underline{aL}\,.
$$

You can also show ($\Leftarrow$) in similar way.

---

The equality $(\spadesuit)$ is basically integral of parts. To see:
$$
\int_0^{x} f(t) dt = \frac{1}{x^{a-1}} \int_{0}^x t^{a-1}f(t) dt - \lim_{u\to 0+} \Big[ \frac{1}{u^{a-1}} \int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big] 
-\int_{0}^x \frac{1-a}{u^a}\Big(\int_{0}^u t^{a-1}f(t) dt \Big) du 
$$
for $x>0$, we first define the function on $x\in(0,\infty)$:
$$
F_a(x) = \int_{0}^x t^{a-1}f(t) dt\,.
$$
Then the above equation becomes:
$$
\int_0^{x} f(t) dt = \frac{1}{x^{a-1}} F_a(x) - \lim_{u\to 0+} \Big[ \frac{1}{u^{a-1}} F(u) \Big] 
-\int_{0}^x \frac{1-a}{u^a} F(u) du\,. 
$$

If you consider that the integral from $0$ is actually defined as a limit,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{x} f(t) dt  &= \lim_{u\to 0+}  \int_u^{x} f(t) dt =  \lim_{u\to 0+}  \int_u^{x} \frac{1}{t^{a-1}} t^{a-1} f(t) dt = \lim_{u\to 0+}  \int_u^{x} \frac{1}{t^{a-1}} F_a'(t) dt\\
&=\frac{1}{x^{a-1}} F_a(x) - \lim_{u\to 0+} \Big[ \frac{1}{u^{a-1}} F_a(u) \Big] 
-\int_{0}^x \frac{1-a}{t^a} F_a(t) dt\,.
\end{align}
$$

The existence of final term integral ($=$ existence of limit) is verified from the fact $t^{-a}F_a(t)\stackrel{t\to 0+}{\longrightarrow} L$. Concretely, the value is same with $(1-a)\int_{0}^x G_a(t) dt$, where $G_a(t)$ is *continuous function* at $[\pmb{0},\infty)$, defined as $G_a(t) = t^{-a}F_a(t)$ on $t > 0$ and $G_a(0) = L$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x} f(t) dt$ is the “$b=1$” case, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks! Just corrected.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on how you got the second equality in your proof of the forward direction?

Comment: Please check additional stuffs